# c++: pass function as parameter to another function

Tags: c++, tree, traversal

i am currently implementing a binary tree in c++ and i want to traverse it with a function called in_order().

is there any way to pass a function as an argument, so that i can do things like below (without having to write the code to traverse the list more than once)?

```
struct tree_node; // and so on
class  tree;      // and so on

void print_node () {
  // some stuff here
}

// some other functions

tree mytree();

// insert some nodes

mytree.in_order(print_node);
mytree.in_order(push_node_to_stack);
mytree.in_order(something_else);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in a number of ways. Here are two common possibilities.

**Old-style function pointers**

```
class mytree
{
    // typedef for a function pointer to act
    typedef void (*node_fn_ptr)(tree_node&);

    void in_order(node_fn_ptr)
    {
        tree_node* pNode;

        while (/* ... */)
        {
        // traverse...
        // ... lots of code

        // found node!
            (*fnptr)(*pNode);
            // equivalently: fnptr(*pNode)
        }
    }
};

void MyFunc(tree_node& tn)
{
    // ...
}

void sample(mytree& tree)
{
    // called with a default constructed function:
    tree.inorder(&MyFunc);
    // equivalently: tree.inorder(MyFunc);
}
```

**Using functors**

With a template member, works with function pointers

```
class mytree
{
    // typedef for a function pointer to act
    typedef void (*node_fn_ptr)(tree_node&);

    template<class F>
    void in_order(F f)
    {
        tree_node* pNode;

        while (/* ... */)
        {
        // traverse...
        // ... lots of code

        // found node!
            f(*pNode);
        }
    }
};

struct ExampleFunctor
{
    void operator()(tree_node& node)
    {
        // do something with node
    }
}

void sample(mytree& tree)
{
    // called with a default constructed function:
    tree.inorder(ExampleFunctor());
}
```

Comment: +1: hoping the OP will use the new style rather the C-style :)

Comment: +1 - It may be worth adding a note explaining the pros and cons of these two methods though. (functors can store state, and are easier inlined by the compiler)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a function pointer as a parameter to `in_order`. You may also need to overload it, in case the passed functions' signatures don't match. For functions like `print_node`, declare in_order like this (provided its return type is `void` as well):

```
void tree::in_order( void (*)() )
{
   //implementation
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the visitor pattern instead.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

The base visitor class should have a virtual method to operate on a node. Pass the visitor as an argument to your in_order method.
Then derive your visitor as many times as you want for any operation you want to do.

Comment: Actually the visitor pattern is probably more powerful than what you actually want to achieve. The strategy pattern should suffice.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: it's both not quite what i was looking for. i think that both would be too bloated for a small binary tree class. interesting concepts, though!

Comment: Yeah a little bit more bloated, but probably more powerful.

And when I work in C++ I try to avoid at all cost static functions.